# creating a facebook event using facebook api and sending invitations using flex mobile

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, flex-mobile

i am creating an app for iphone in which a user can loging using facebook and when he click invite an event must be created in facebook and it should be sent to facebook friends. can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

kindly refer to the facebook developer documentation for references related to creating event :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

You can user FBFriendPickerDelegate for selecting friends and then using their ids for inviting  to event